# Cannot read property '<<componentName>>' of undefined

Tags: json, node.js, middleware

I am trying to read the property of a ng-model being set in my template and angular batarang actually shows the value.

However, when I try to access the value from the controller, it says cannot read property of undefined.

Please can someone indicate what is going wrong.

```
<input type="text" class="span9 typeahead"  ng-model="onboarding.componentName" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source="{{getComponentNames}}"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.saveOnboarding=function(){
     var dat=$scope.onboarding.componentName;

    $http.post('/onboarding/addOnboarding',dat)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        window.alert('Data Successfully saved!!');
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        window.alert(status + 'Data Save Failed!!');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because I was using this in a Bootstrap modal.

Bootstrap's modal's scope cannot be used directly in the controller. 
In order to use the modal's scope variables, we need to set the ng-model as $parent.onboarding.componentName

Add $parent to make the scope visible in the main one.